# Type error 'x' is not a function on the protractor with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, protractor

I receive a TypeError in the console when trying to use javascript ECMAScript 6 in the protractor. 
I want to have a Base Class with all actions that protractor do and import it to another Page objects. Also logger all actions that protractor do on the base page.

package.json

```
{
   "name": "Protractor-end-to-end-test-framework",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.8.3",
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
      "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
      "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
      "jasmine-allure-reporter": "^1.0.2",
      "log4js": "^6.2.1",
      "moment": "^2.24.0",
      "protractor": "^5.4.2"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "test": "webdriver-manager start --standalone && protractor config.js"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "eslint": "^6.8.0",
      "eslint-plugin-protractor": "^2.1.1"
   }
}
```

config.js

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./tests/test.js'], 
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',

      chromeOptions: {
         args: [ "--window-size=1920,1024" ]
       }
    },
    //Global configuration
    baseUrl: 'https://facebook.com',

    //Allure configuration
    onPrepare: () => {
      require("@babel/register");
      var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter());
      jasmine.getEnv().afterEach( done => {
        if(done.status === "failed") {
          browser.takeScreenshot().then(png => {
            allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', () => {
              return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
            }, 'image/png')();
            done();
          })
        }});
    }
}
```

test.js

```
'use strict'

import { get } from '../page_objects/base_page';
import { fillLoginAndPasswordIntoWindow } from '../page_objects/pre_login_page';
import { getUserName, getPassword } from '../utils/constants';
describe('Collection data', () => {

    beforeAll(() => {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        get(browser.baseUrl);
    });

    it('Demo tests', () => {
        fillLoginAndPasswordIntoWindow(getUserName, getPassword);
    });
});
```

base.js

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';

const log = require('../logger.config');
const constants = require('../utils/constants');

const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const GLOBAL_TIMEOUT = constants.getTimeout;

export default class Base {
    constructor() {

    }

    get = url => {
        browser.get(url);
        log.info(`Navigate to the ${url}`);
    }

    click = element => {
        element.click();
        log.info(`Click on the ${element}`);
    }

    enterText = (element, text) => {
        element.sendKeys(text);
        log.info(`Enter text ${text} to the ${element}`);
    }

    getText = element => {
        log.info(`Get text from the element ${element}`);
        return element.getText();
    }

    getAttribute = (element, attribute) => {
        log.info(`Get attribute ${attribute} from element ${element}`);
        return element.getAttribute(attribute);
    }

    sDisplayed = element => {
        log.info("Is element displayed on the page");
        return element.isDisplayed();
    }

    //Wait section
    waitToBePresent = element => {
        log.info("Wait to element present");
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element), GLOBAL_TIMEOUT);
    }

    waitToBeInvisible = element => {
        log.info("Wait to element invisible");
        browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(element), GLOBAL_TIMEOUT);
    }

    waitToBeVisible = element => {
        browser.wait( () => {
            browser.sleep(2000);
            return element.isDisplayed()
            .then( isDisplayed => {
                return isDisplayed;
            }, error => {
                return false;
            });
        }, GLOBAL_TIMEOUT);
    }

    wait = timeout => {
        log.info(`Wait ${timeout} seconds`);
        browser.sleep(timeout * 1000);
    }


    //Alert section
    waitToAlertPresent = () => {
        try {
            browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), GLOBAL_TIMEOUT);
            log.info(`Wait to alert present`);
        } catch (error) {
            log.info(`No allert present in the page`);
        }
    }

    enterTextAlert = text => {
        waitToAlertPresent();
        browser.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(text);
        log.info(`Enter text ${text} to the alert window`);
    }

    acceptAlert = () => {
        waitToAlertPresent();
        browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
        log.info(`Accept alert`);
    }
}
```

I expected that protractor should work with javascript with ECMAScript 6. But now error occurred in the console log. 
Stack:

```
Message:
    Failed: (0 , _base_page.get) is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: (0 , _base_page.get) is not a function
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/tomashgombosh/Documents/protractor-framework/tests/test.js:10:9)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1077:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2505:12)
        at schedulerExecute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2974:25
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the export. I do not need to have a class to export all of the arrow functions. I need only add

```
export const get = url => {
    browser.get(url);
    log.info(`Navigate to the ${url}`);
}
```

That help me to resolve the problem. 
Bad export was my problem